# What is a PED fuse?

Tags: fuses

I have a 1996 bus with some things that look like metal encased fuses connected to some wires in a battery box. They are marked as PED. Does anyone know what PED fuses are? Google hasn't been very helpful.

Comment: A manufacturer's name perhaps. [PED](https://pedelectrical.co.uk/fuses/) are in that industrial area.

Answer (score 1):

PED stands for "Packard Electrical Division" (of General Motors). They would be the manufacturer.

See, for example, this connector (photo from eBay):

[image]

You will need the fuse part number or some other specifications to order replacements, but usually there are compatible parts from various manufacturers.

Comment: It looks like waterproof connectors ... Seen on connections for robot lawn mowers ... Unless I am wrong ...